# Question format in Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, support, asking-questions, rules

Are there rules or formats for questions in Stack Overflow?

Which words should be avoided?

Comment: Naughty words like "f*ddlesticks" should be avoided.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more context?  Did you or someone else perhaps post something that garnered a negative response?  This is pretty hard to answer otherwise. ;)

Comment: There's always this: [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: @jmort253 sometime I ask the question that i don't know.But question is close and get down vote.

Comment: @9ine Could you please provide a link to the question so we have a bit more context?

Comment: @9ine Perhaps you mean [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12277091/1726343)?

Comment: @Asad Yes. Please , What is wrong in my question? At that time i really don't know. So i asked.

Comment: @9ine - Please read [our FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) before posting a question anywhere. Didn't you read [the comment from Andrew Thompson](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12277091/what-is-the-meaning-of-thread-dump#comment16465055_12277091).

Comment: It's not about words, it's about context and contents of your question. Stack Overflow expects professional questions that show some research, not trivial questions with trivial answers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The question you've asked is:

> I want to know what is java thread dump. please share me some knowledge.

Now, in the year 2012, we live in a world where information, where knowledge, can be found in every corner of the Internet. Most likely, you aren't the first person to wonder what a Java Thread dump is. Someone else most likely already asked this question, and it's just a matter of using Google to find that information.

In fact, the very [first result on Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+thread+dump&aq=f&oq=java+thread+dump&aqs=chrome.0.57j5j61j60j0l2.2558&sugexp=chrome,mod=18&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) appears to define what a thread dump is.

Please don't take this the wrong way, but your question implies that you're very new to the Internet or that you're just lazy. Most people are happy to help people who put effort into trying to acquire knowledge but not those who don't. This is because it's extremely hard to teach someone something when they don't put effort in themselves. In fact, many people who try to help those who don't put effort end up feeling very frustrated and drained.

**So, from now on, commit to doing the following:**

- Always do a search before posting a question on a forum or Q&A site. Chances are, the information is already out there, so there's no need to waste anyone else's time, including your own! ;)
- If you don't find what you're looking for, be sure to include this in your question. If the information you found was confusing, explain what it was that you didn't understand. This gives answerers a place to start in order to help you understand the concept. It really helps to meet people halfway so they don't have to write a book. :)
- Always be sure to do your own research before posting a question. This lets people know that you're serious, and most people will be more respectful towards you and be more willing to help.

Now, the fact that you're here asking how you can improve implies you're not lazy, just sort of new to these concepts. So I really think you'll improve and be a great community member!  Hope this helps!

Comment: thank. I really appreciate on your answer.At that time I already search in Google but my understanding is confuse that why i was asked.

Comment: One thing you could do is explain in your question what you didn't understand. You could also cite the source as well. and quote the parts you found confusing. As an aside, I'm going to go out on a limb and assume that English isn't your first language. If that's the case, then I think it's okay to mention that as well. Anything you can add that can help an answerer know what the challenge is will help.  Good luck! :)